# почему по localhost форма ajax отсылается а на хосте нет выдает "405 method not allowed"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
   <div class="dataTables_filter">
      <form id="dataTable_filter_batch" method="post" action="" class="form-search">
         <label>Search by:
         <input type="text" name="sbatch" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Batch #" aria-controls="dataTable">
         </label>
         <button type="submit" class="click-search" data-url="/search/batch/" data-form_id="dataTable_filter_batch"><i class="voyager-search"></i></button>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
//search
    $(".click-search").click(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            var ajax_form = el.data('form_id');
            var url = el.data('url');
            var result_block = $('#result_block');
           
            sendAjaxForm(result_block, ajax_form, url);
            
            return false; 
    });
    
    
    function sendAjaxForm(result_block, ajax_form, url) {
        
        $.ajax({
            url:     url, 
            type:     "POST", 
            dataType: "html", 
            data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  
            
            success: function(response) { 
                    var result =$.parseJSON(response);
                

                        $(result_block).html(clone_row);
                    }else {
                        $(result_block).html('<tr class="odd"><td valign="top" colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty">No matching records found</td></tr>');
                    }  
                    
            },
            error: function(response) { 
                $(result_block).html('<tr class="odd"><td valign="top" colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty">Data not sent</td></tr>');
            }
        });
        
    }
```

Comment: что в адресной строке? какой код на сервере?

Comment: в адресной строке ничего не меняется, оно даже не доходит до сетрвера срабатывает же error: function(response) { 
                $(result_block).html('<tr class="odd"><td valign="top" colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty">Data not sent</td></tr>');
            }

ну на локальном все работает то

Comment: Изучайте ответ сервера, смотрите логи, проверяйте по stack trace. Сервер считает, что отправлять post-запросы по вашему пути запрещено. Еще было бы правильно в JQ повесить выполнение отправки AJAX на событие submit формы, используя функцию preventDefault. И вместо data-url путь более правильно указать путь в атрибуте action.